# How to WhiteLabel SendGrid Email Links with Azure default domain(xxx.azurewebsites.net)?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, sendgrid, white-labelling

Our website is hosted in Windows Azure with default domain name (xxx.azurewebsites.net). We use SendGrid to send emails. We want to whitelabel email links. [This](https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Settings/Whitelabel/index.html) page shows how to white label email links. but it looks I need to add CNAME records to subdomain.  How can I add CNAME recoreds or subdomain to azure default domain name? Is it possible to do it with default azure domain name?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I add CNAME recoreds or subdomain to azure default domain name? Is it possible to do it with default azure domain name?

We can’t add subdomain or CNAME recoreds to azurewebsites.net, because we are not the owner of azurewebsites.net.

We could only add subdomain or CNAME on our own domain, so I suggest you could try to buy one and map it to your web application.

More details about how to use custom domain in azure, you could refer to follow link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-custom-domain-name